# nVidia Quadro 600 - Dual-Link DVI bad detection

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, nvidia-quadro

I just got by new NVidia Quadro 600 PCI-e with a dual-link DVI-I and I got a small problem when I try to install my second monitor using a DVI to DVI+VGA adapter... The VGA monitor is working very well, but the one in DVI, not detected at all. But also, in the `Screen Resolution` window, I see my Sony TV (the one in VGA) as my V233H monitor (the one in DVI).

And there is my question: why my card does not detect the both monitors correctly and how I can fix it? I tried searching on Google but without success...

Comment: Someone has an idea??